# Why do I need to implement FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback when using FragmentCompat.requestPermissions?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I'm reading [the documentation of FragmentCompat.requestPermissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)):

> Your fragment has to implement
>   [FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html) and the results of
>   permission requests will be delivered to its
>   [onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])).

I extend [android.app.Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). `android.app.Fragment` doesn't implement `FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`. And I don't implement `FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` in my class. I don't see a compile-time error (this class must be abstract or implement the methods of its interfaces). See the code below:

```
public static class Frag extends Fragment implements FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

}
```

Besides, when I call FragmentCompat.requestPermissions, the method [onRequestPermissionsResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) of my fragment is called. So why does the documentation say it's necessary to implement `FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` when `FragmentCompat.requestPermissions` is used?

Answer (score 2):

when the permission dialog is shown to a user by FragmentCompat.requestPermissions, and when the user allows or denies the permission, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback is called, in this code you should write what happens after user allows or denies this permission